# How to allow only one request to perform action and reject all other concurrent requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, locking, race-condition

When multiple concurrent requests try to call controller reject action. In race conditions, it generates same `comments` multiple times, although one of the `request` and `order` is rejected. But in race conditions, `request` cannot identify `order` was already rejected by one of the `request` because all these processes executes in very little amount of time before `order` changed to reject. To avoid this race condition issue, I have locked `request` and `order` in DB row level. But it's not working. Here are my sample codes:

I am using Ruby 2.5.8, Rails 5.0.7.

**My Model**

- Order has many requests
- Request has one approvers

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  def self.reject_request(key)
    request = Request.where(:reject_key => key).first
    order = request&.order
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if request.blank? || order.blank?
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if request.rejected? || order.rejected?

    order.lock!
    request.lock!

    request.status = 'rejected'
    request.save!
    order.update(status: 'rejected')
    true
  end
end
```

**My Controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def reject
    @request ||= Request.find_by(reject_key: params[:reject_key])
    @order = @request&.purchase_order

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      rejected = Request.reject_request(params[:reject_key])
      @order.comments.create(comment: "Order rejected by approver: #{@request.approver.name}") if rejected
      if rejected
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Rejected'
      else
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Try again!'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Problem**

There should be only one correct comment, but there are more incorrect comments generated as shown below.

> Order rejected by approver: Joe (correct)
>
> Order rejected by approver: Jack (not correct)
>
> Order rejected by approver: Joe (not correct)
>
> Order rejected by approver: Jack (not correct)

It's working when reject action is executed by clicking on reject link through application. But when multiple requests are running through multi-threaded process, then it does not work as I described above. How to allow only one request to perform the action and reject all other actions? Any feedback would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lock an order before checking it's status.

If 2 concurrent requests execute check for `request.rejected? || order.rejected?` simultaneously with your solution, both gets `false` and proceed consequentially under the lock.

**Changes for your model**

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  def self.reject_request(key)
    request = Request.where(:reject_key => key).first
    order = request&.order

    # make sure both request and order objects are not empty
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if request.blank? || order.blank?

    # lock your object
    order.lock!
    request.lock!

    # put your conditions here after the `lock`
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if request.rejected? || order.rejected?


    request.status = 'rejected'
    request.save!
    order.update(status: 'rejected')
    true
  end
end
```